# Combine rows by group with differing NAs in each row

Tags: r, grouping

I can't find an exact answer to this problem, so I hope I'm not duplicating a question.

I have a dataframe as follows

```
groupid  col1  col2  col3  col4
   1      0     n     NA     2    
   1      NA    NA    2      2
```

What I'm trying to convey with this is that there are duplicate IDs where the total information is spread across both rows and I want to combine these rows to get all the information into one row.  How do I go about this?

I've tried to play around with group_by and paste but that ends up making the data messier (getting 22 instead of 2 in col4 for example) and sum() does not work because some columns are strings and those that are not are categorical variables and summing them would change the information.

Is there something I can do to collapse the rows and leave consistent data unchanged while filling in NAs?

EDIT:

Sorry desired output is as follows:

```
groupid  col1  col2  col3  col4
   1      0     n     2     2
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567254/496803 Or even this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601267/merging-similar-rows-in-a-data-frame/33601491

Comment: Oh that second link might work, I'll give it a try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036294/collapsing-rows-where-some-are-all-na-others-are-disjoint-with-some-nas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove all cells with "NA" value by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376531/how-can-i-remove-all-cells-with-na-value-by-columns)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you want ? `zoo`+`dplyr` also check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060439/r-merge-rows-and-fill-empty-positions-with-group-by-and/45060711?noredirect=1#comment77339816_45060711) here

```
df %>%
    group_by(groupid) %>%
    mutate_all(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE)))%>%filter(row_number()==n())


# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   groupid [1]
  groupid  col1  col2  col3  col4
    <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1       1     0     n     2     2
```

**EDIT1**

without the filter , will give back whole dataframe.

```
    df %>%
        group_by(groupid) %>%
        mutate_all(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE)))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   groupid [1]
  groupid  col1  col2  col3  col4
    <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1       1     0     n    NA     2
2       1     0     n     2     2
```

`filter` here, just slice the last one, `na.locf` will carry on the previous not `NA` value, which mean the last row in your group is what you want.

Also base on @ thelatemail recommended. you can do the following , give back the same answer.

```
df %>% group_by(groupid) %>% summarise_all(funs(.[!is.na(.)][1]))
```

**EDIT2**

Assuming you have conflict and you want to show them all.

```
df <- read.table(text="groupid  col1  col2  col3  col4
   1      0     n     NA     2    
                 1      1    NA    2      2",
                 header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 df
  groupid col1 col2 col3 col4
1       1    0    n   NA    2
2       1    1(#)<NA>    2    2(#)
df %>%
    group_by(groupid) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(toString(unique(na.omit(.)))))#unique for duplicated like col4
  groupid  col1  col2  col3  col4
    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1       1  0, 1     n     2   2
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option with just `dplyr` is just to take the first non-NA value when available. You can do

```
dd <- read.table(text="groupid  col1  col2  col3  col4
1      0     n     NA     2    
1      NA    NA    2      2", header=T)

dd %>% 
  group_by(groupid) %>% 
  summarise_all(~first(na.omit(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to draw the desired output in this case? Converting data.frame into anothre type as.vector(), as.matrix() and grouping/factoring might help.

UPDATE:
Finding a unique elements for each column and omitting NAs.

```
df<-data.frame(groupid=c(1,1), col1=c(0,NA), col2=c('n', NA), col3=c(NA,2),  col4=c(2,2)) # your input
out<-data.frame(df[1,]) # where the output is stored, duplicate retaining 1 row
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) out[,i]<-na.omit(unique(df[,i]))
print(out)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16766375)

Comment: I did not have priviledges to post comment yesterday. This was as much as I could do. It was necessary to clarify the question and everything I did was ethically sound.

Comment: Then you yould do it now and remove this answer.

Comment: The answer is updated now, no need to remove it. As I said, the commenting was not possible, apology for that.