# How can I remove all cells with "NA" value by columns

Tags: r

This question is not a duplicate because my `data.frame` **does not have the same amount of `NA` values** in all Columns and therefore the solution mentioned in that question does not work.

I have a `data.frame` with a lot of `NA` values and I would like to delete all cells (important: not rows or columns, cells) that have NA values. The original would look like this:

```
A  B
1  NA
NA 2
2  NA
NA NA
NA NA
NA 4
3  5
```

The desired result would look like this:

```
A  B
1  2
2  4 
3  5
```

The number of columns would have to stay the same, but it does not matter if the values remain on the same rows. They can just be moved up.

I could image one could delete all cells with the condition NA (maybe with apply) and get the result. Or maybe a simple sorting ?

Thanks.

Update:

```
A   B   C
1       3
    2   
4       3

    1   2

3       5
        4
    9   
7       1
```

Comment: Try `data.frame(lapply(df1, na.omit))`

Comment: does each column have the same number of NA? If not, you'll have a problem bc data.frames require columns of the same length. You could just work with a normal list instead.

Comment: No, there are a lot of NAs and few real values and they are not the same number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP has requested to remove the `NA`s columnwise but has pointed out that there might be different numbers of NA in each column.

This can be solved using `data.table` in two steps:

```
library(data.table)
# step 1: coerce to data.table in place, move NAs to the bottom of each column, 
# maintain the original order of non-NA values
result <- data.table(DF)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])]
```

> ```
>      A  B  C
>  1:  1  2  3
>  2:  4  1  3
>  3:  3  9  2
>  4:  7 NA  5
>  5: NA NA  4
>  6: NA NA  1
>  7: NA NA NA
>  8: NA NA NA
>  9: NA NA NA
> 10: NA NA NA
> ```

```
# step 2: trim result
# either using Reduce
result[!result[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na))]]

# or using zoo::na.trim()
zoo::na.trim(result, is.na = "all")
```

> ```
>     A  B C
> 1:  1  2 3
> 2:  4  1 3
> 3:  3  9 2
> 4:  7 NA 5
> 5: NA NA 4
> 6: NA NA 1
> ```

So, there will be some `NA`s at the end of each colummn unavoidably because all columns in a data.frame have the same length.

Or, alternatively, only complete rows can be kept using the `is.na` parameter to `na.trim()`:

```
zoo::na.trim(result, is.na = "any")
```

> ```
>    A B C
> 1: 1 2 3
> 2: 4 1 3
> 3: 3 9 2
> ```

#### An alternative solution

As mentioned before, `data.frame`s and `cbind()` expect all column vectors to have the same length. Here is an alternative solution without `data.table` which uses the `cbind.fill()` function from the `rowr` package which pads vectors with the `fill` value until the same length:

```
setNames(do.call(function(...) rowr::cbind.fill(..., fill = NA), lapply(DF, na.omit)),
         colnames(DF))
```

> ```
>    A  B C
> 1  1  2 3
> 2  4  1 3
> 3  3  9 2
> 4  7 NA 5
> 5 NA NA 4
> 6 NA NA 1
> ```

#### Data

As supplied by the OP in the update:

```
DF <- structure(list(A = c(1L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 7L), 
    B = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA), C = c(3L, 
    NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("A", "B", 
"C"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try ,Base on @UweBlock's Data and your updated question.

```
dat=as.data.frame(na.omit(apply(dat,2,function (x) x[order(is.na(x))])))

dat
  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 4 1 3
3 3 9 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get an empty variable/file after using this . Does the initial dat need to be converted to anything specific (data.frame, list, matrix) ? Or what am I missing here.

Comment: @user413734 I assuming you are working with data.frame

Comment: Yes I do. After I run your code I get chr[0, 1:255] in the environment panel of Rstudio. I have 255 columns in my original data. All transformations before that show the same number of columns and rows. It seems this code gets rid of all rows where NA is and all occurrences of NA in a column. Any ideas what I could try else. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just tried your code with the updated example file and even though it did in principle what was expected it left out the the values 7 in row A and 5, 4, 1 in row C. I believe it has to be the same amount of values (3). But for me it does not matter if the rows are kept intakt to the original file.

Comment: @user413734, Then , you can just using  `apply(dat,2,function (x) x[order(is.na(x))])`

Comment: @Wen Please, can you mention that your answer turns the data.frame silently into a matrix?

Comment: @UweBlock   The first edit of the question , Op mention it is matrix, If it is datad.frame , i will recommend akrun's answer

Comment: @wen With the updated sample data with varying number of `NA`s, Akrun's answer will stop with an errror messages. According to the edit history, the the OP mentioned `apply` which may have caused the misunderstanding.

Comment: @UweBlock      Read thru the updated question and  Edit my answer ~Thank you for your help~ :)