# combine rows in data frame containing NA to make complete row

Tags: r, coalesce, tidyverse

I know this is a duplicate Q but I can't seem to find the post again

Using the following data

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2),B=c(NA,2,NA,4),C=c(3,NA,NA,5),D=c(NA,2,3,NA),E=c(5,NA,NA,4))

  A  B  C  D  E
  1 NA  3 NA  5
  1  2 NA  2 NA
  2 NA NA  3 NA
  2  4  5 NA  4
```

Grouping by `A`, I'd like the following output using a `tidyverse` solution

```
  A  B  C  D  E
  1  2  3  2  5
  2  4  5  3  4
```

I have many groups in `A`. I think I saw an answer using `coalesce` but am unsure how to get it work. I'd like a **solution that works with `characters`** as well. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine rows by group with differing NAs in each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201654/combine-rows-by-group-with-differing-nas-in-each-row)

Comment: `coalesce(df[1,], df[2,])`.

Comment: Thanks Wen: similar approach to `d.b.`'s answer, which should work, but I'm wondering if there's also a solution involving `coalesce`

Comment: Thanks Rui: please see my update. I have many groups in `A`. I'd like a `dplyr` chained solution for that reason

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515180/dplyr-how-to-find-the-first-non-missing-string-by-groups

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove all cells with "NA" value by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376531/how-can-i-remove-all-cells-with-na-value-by-columns)

Comment: @RuiBarradas `coalesce(df[1,], df[2,])` returns only one row but not two as requested.

Comment: Some more solutions in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/28036294/786542

Comment: `coalesce` is a bad option here, since it really only takes the first non-missing value, and won't perform any of the grouping you want. In other words, `coalesce` will work if you have identified the rows that are matches for each other, excepting NAs, but otherwise is not a solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to put the `coalesce_by_column` function inside the `dplyr` pipeline, but this works:

```
coalesce_by_column <- function(df) {
  return(coalesce(df[1], df[2]))
}

df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise_all(coalesce_by_column)

##       A     B     C     D     E
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1     2     3     2     5
## 2     2     4     5     3     4
```

---

Edit: include @Jon Harmon's solution for more than 2 members of a group

```
# Supply lists by splicing them into dots:
coalesce_by_column <- function(df) {
  return(dplyr::coalesce(!!! as.list(df)))
}

df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise_all(coalesce_by_column)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>       A     B     C     D     E
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     3     2     5
#> 2     2     4     5     3     4
```

Comment: Please see my updated example and I have edited my post to indicate that I have many groups in `A`, which is why I wanted a `dplyr` chained solution

Comment: From the dplyr::coalesce help:
# Supply lists by splicing them into dots:
vecs <- list(
  c(1, 2, NA, NA, 5),
  c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5)
)
coalesce(!!! vecs)

So, based on that, I got coalesce_by_column to work for more than 2 members of a group:
coalesce_by_column <- function(df) {
  return(dplyr::coalesce(!!! as.list(df)))
}

Hope that helps!

Comment: looks like this does not work on character columns. Just value.

Answer (score 18):

We can use `fill` to fill all the missing values. And then filter just one row for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "up") %>%
  slice(1)
```

And thanks to @Roger-123, the above code can be further simplified as follows.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
  slice(1)
```

Comment: This is the best answer that is simple AND provides a tidyverse based answer, as the original question requested.

Comment: This could also be simplified by changing the first fill line from `"down"` to `"downup"` and removing the second fill line.

Comment: @Roger-123 Thanks for your comment. I just updated the post including your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Not `tidyverse` but here's one base R solution

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1),B=c(NA,2),C=c(3,NA),D=c(NA,2),E=c(5,NA))
sapply(df, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
#A B C D E 
#1 2 3 2 5
```

With updated data

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$A), function(a) sapply(a, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])))
#  A B C D E
#1 1 2 3 2 5
#2 2 4 5 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks, this could work in a `mutate` statement. I'll wait for a few other answers nonetheless

Answer (score 4):

Here is an even more general solution (using `unique`, `na.omit` to sort of create `coalesce`), which can handle more than two rows with overlapping information.  Super simply and forward.

```
> df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,2),B=c(NA,2,NA,4,4),C=c(3,NA,NA,5,NA),D=c(NA,2,3,NA,NA),E=c(5,NA,NA,4,4))

> df
  A  B  C  D  E
1 1 NA  3 NA  5
2 1  2 NA  2 NA
3 2 NA NA  3 NA
4 2  4  5 NA  4
5 2  4 NA NA  4

> df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_all(funs( na.omit(unique(.)) ))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
      A     B     C     D     E
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3     2     5
2     2     4     5     3     4
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to `summarise` by taking the `max` across all columns for each group with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ max(., na.rm = T)))
```

**Output**

```
      A     B     C     D     E
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3     2     5
2     2     4     5     3     4
```

Another option with using `na.omit` and `unique`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ na.omit(unique(.))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A different `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -A, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(A, var) %>%
 distinct(val) %>%
 spread(var, val)

      A     B     C     D     E
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3     2     5
2     2     4     5     3     4
```

Here it, first, performs a wide-to-long data-transformation, excluding the "A" column and removing the missing values. Second, it groups by "A" column and the variable names. Third, it removes the duplicate values. Finally, it returns the data to its original wide format.

Answer (score 1):

This is functionally identical to @Oriol Mirosa's answer without requiring a custom function:

EDIT: NAs must be omitted as per @thelatemail's comment. This answer was also given by @MrFlick in the duplicate thread linked above.

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_all(~first(na.omit(.)))
```

I wanted to add to this as it seems to come up regularly for me and I've revisited this thread many times. @Oriol Mirosa's answer works, however I'm resistant to it because it's just complex enough to be difficult to remember (hence my return to this thread).

Personally, I also don't like writing small custom functions like if I don't need to. Attempting to substitute `coalesce_by_column` with the actual `coalesce` call results in type errors (which I find strange as the rows aren't interacting with each other but whatever). This can be resolved by first doing `mutate_all(as.character)`, however my goal here is to minimize syntax so it's easily remembered on the fly.

Furthermore, this substitution changes the behavior such that non-identical values within a column throws an error (why things sometimes behave slightly differently within a function is beyond me). This behavior may be preferred in some situations, however in that case I would recommend @Jerry T's solution as there is no custom function and the ones used are familiar, readable, and the ordering of them (`na.omit` and `unique`) isn't relevant.

Comment: This gives a bunch of `NA` values in the output if an `NA` happens to be the first value.

Comment: Thanks I didn't catch that last night