# Combining rows with duplicate values and NAs [without using tidyverse]

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame which has multiple rows per ID. I would like to combine those rows to get 1 row for each ID and combine the respective values which can be either a `number` or `NA` (which I would like to ignore).

I am not sure I can use aggregate() here; Generally I want for each ID values in  columns (V1-V4), to be set to a number if there is a value which is not `NA`.

Input:

```
    ID V1 V2 V3 V4
1  04C  6 NA NA  9
2  04C NA  9 NA  9
3  0F0 NA  5 NA  4
4  0F0 NA NA  7  4
5  0F0 NA  5  7 NA
6  167  8 NA NA NA
7  167  8 10  5 NA
8  167  8 10 NA NA
9  167  8 NA  5 NA
10 2D7  3  3 NA  1
```

Output:

```
   ID V1 V2 V3 V4
1 04C  6  9 NA  9
2 0F0 NA  5  7  4
3 167  8 10  5 NA
4 2D7  3  3 NA  1
```

I came up with a solution, unfortunately it is very slow but at least it avoids creating a tibble.

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
   row0 <- df[i-1,1]
   row1 <- df[i,1]  
   if (row0==row1) {
      for(j in 2:5) {
         if (is.na(df[i,j])) {
            df[i,j] <- df[i-1,j]
         }
      }
      df[i-1,1] <- "NA"
   }
}
dfclean <- subset(df, V0!="NA")
```

Comment: Duplicate of [combine rows in data frame containing NA to make complete row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515218/combine-rows-in-data-frame-containing-na-to-make-complete-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(ID, var) %>%
 distinct(val) %>%
 spread(var, val)

  ID       V1    V2    V3    V4
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 04C       6     9    NA     9
2 0F0      NA     5     7     4
3 167       8    10     5    NA
4 2D7       3     3    NA     1
```

Comment: `tidyverse`is very interesting, thank you.
I had to install it first of course and also install `bindrcpp`.

Comment: Works great but how can I save the output to a new data frame?

Comment: `df_new <- df %>% ... `

Answer (score 0):

Could also go for:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_all(~ if (any(!is.na(.))) first(na.omit(.)) else NA)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  ID       V1    V2    V3    V4
  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 04C       6     9    NA     9
2 0F0      NA     5     7     4
3 167       8    10     5    NA
4 2D7       3     3    NA     1
```