# Fill in values based on previous day in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume
2020-10-28,1384,1384,1384,1384,1384,0
2020-10-29,1297,1297,1297,1297,1297,0
2020-10-30,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-11-02,1284,1284,1284,1284,1284,0
2020-11-03,1263,1263,1263,1263,1263,0
2020-11-04,1224,1224,1224,1224,1224,0
2020-11-05,1194,1194,1194,1194,1194,0
2020-11-06,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-09,1207,1207,1207,1207,1207,0
2020-11-10,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,0
```

and I wanted to fill in values for say 10-31 and 11-1 to contain the values from the previous trading day (10-30). How is this easily accomplished in R? I feel as though library(tidyr) and complete fit into this picture somehow?

Expected representation would be:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume
2020-10-28,1384,1384,1384,1384,1384,0
2020-10-29,1297,1297,1297,1297,1297,0
2020-10-30,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-10-31,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-11-01,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-11-02,1284,1284,1284,1284,1284,0
2020-11-03,1263,1263,1263,1263,1263,0
2020-11-04,1224,1224,1224,1224,1224,0
2020-11-05,1194,1194,1194,1194,1194,0
2020-11-06,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-07,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-08,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-09,1207,1207,1207,1207,1207,0
2020-11-10,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,0
```

Requested dput output

```
structure(list(Date = c("2020-10-28", "2020-10-29", "2020-10-30", 
"2020-11-02", "2020-11-03", "2020-11-04", "2020-11-05", "2020-11-06", 
"2020-11-09", "2020-11-10"), Open = c(1384L, 1297L, 1283L, 1284L, 
1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L), High = c(1384L, 1297L, 
1283L, 1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L), Low = c(1384L, 
1297L, 1283L, 1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L
), Close = c(1384L, 1297L, 1283L, 1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 
1196L, 1207L, 1200L), Adjusted_close = c(1384L, 1297L, 1283L, 
1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L), Volume = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Kindly provide a reproducible example of your dataset, by copying the output from `dput(head(my_dataset, 10))`.  Please also provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: Each weekend is 2 missing days, not counting any weekdays trading does not occur. I filled in both Saturday and Sunday to be equal to Friday's values.

Comment: Gotcha!  Sorry, I originally misread your `dput()` example of the *input* as an illustration of the *output*; so my comment was in error and I've deleted it to avoid confusion.  Anyway, [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69756903) is below!

Comment: Did [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69756903) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Here's a solution in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/), which [leverages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518649) the [`tidyr::fill()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html) function to fill in values from earlier rows:

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate 'my_data'.
# ...


my_data %>%
  # Ensure 'Date' column is proper datatype.
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  # Link to full range of dates, with blank rows for missing dates.
  right_join(
    # A temporary dataset with the full range of 'Date's.
    tibble(Date = seq(from = min(.$Date), to = max(.$Date), by = "days")),
    by = "Date"
  ) %>%
  # Sort for filling: earlier above later.
  arrange(Date) %>%
  # Fill blank rows with values above.
  fill(everything(), .direction = "down")
```

## Results

Given `my_data` like the `data.frame` reproduced here

```
my_data <- structure(
  list(
    Date = c(
      "2020-10-28", "2020-10-29", "2020-10-30", "2020-11-02", "2020-11-03",
      "2020-11-04", "2020-11-05", "2020-11-06", "2020-11-09", "2020-11-10"
    ),
    Open = c(
      1384L, 1297L, 1283L, 1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L
    ),
    High = c(
      1384L, 1297L, 1283L, 1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L
    ),
    Low = c(
      1384L, 1297L, 1283L, 1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L
    ),
    Close = c(
      1384L, 1297L, 1283L, 1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L
    ),
    Adjusted_close = c(
      1384L, 1297L, 1283L, 1284L, 1263L, 1224L, 1194L, 1196L, 1207L, 1200L
    ),
    Volume = c(
      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 10L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

this solution should yield a `data.frame` like this:

```
         Date Open High  Low Close Adjusted_close Volume
1  2020-10-28 1384 1384 1384  1384           1384      0
2  2020-10-29 1297 1297 1297  1297           1297      0
3  2020-10-30 1283 1283 1283  1283           1283      0
4  2020-10-31 1283 1283 1283  1283           1283      0
5  2020-11-01 1283 1283 1283  1283           1283      0
6  2020-11-02 1284 1284 1284  1284           1284      0
7  2020-11-03 1263 1263 1263  1263           1263      0
8  2020-11-04 1224 1224 1224  1224           1224      0
9  2020-11-05 1194 1194 1194  1194           1194      0
10 2020-11-06 1196 1196 1196  1196           1196      0
11 2020-11-07 1196 1196 1196  1196           1196      0
12 2020-11-08 1196 1196 1196  1196           1196      0
13 2020-11-09 1207 1207 1207  1207           1207      0
14 2020-11-10 1200 1200 1200  1200           1200      0
```

Answer (score 0):

first Date must be in date format

```
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date)

df %>% 
  full_join(data.frame(Date = seq(min(df$Date), max(df$Date), by = "days")),by = "Date") %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  fill(everything())
```

then make a join with a data that only contains the entire sequence of dates from the database, we sort it and use the fill function to fill them

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Convert to a `zoo` class series `z` using `read.zoo` (this also converts `Date` to `Date` class) and then  merge a zero width zoo object with all dates with `z`.  Fill in the missing values using `na.locf` and finally convert back to data frame using `fortify.zoo`.  If a zoo object is ok as the result then omit the `fortify.zoo` part.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(dat)
out1 <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "day"))) |> 
  na.locf() |>
  fortify.zoo(name = "Date")

# check - target is defined in Note at the end
identical(out1, transform(target, Date = as.Date(Date)))
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** In this alternative we use the following pipeline. Instead of using `merge.zoo`, as above, this convert to ts class and back to expand the dates.

1. Convert `dat` to `zoo` class which also converts the index to `Date` class.
2. Then convert that to `ts` class.  Since that class only supports regularly spaced series the conversion will fill in the values corresponding to missing dates with NA's.
3. `na.locf` will then fill in those NA's.
4. use `fortify.zoo` to convert that back to a data frame.
5. Since `ts` class does not support Date indexes the Date column at this point is just numbers so convert those back to `Date` class.

```
library(zoo)

out2 <- dat |> 
  read.zoo() |>
  as.ts() |>
  na.locf() |>
  fortify.zoo(name = "Date") |>
  transform(Date = as.Date(Date))

# check - target is defined in Note at the end    
identical(out2, transform(target, Date = as.Date(Date)))
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

The input `dat` and output `target` in reproducible form are assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume
2020-10-28,1384,1384,1384,1384,1384,0
2020-10-29,1297,1297,1297,1297,1297,0
2020-10-30,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-10-31,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-11-01,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-11-02,1284,1284,1284,1284,1284,0
2020-11-03,1263,1263,1263,1263,1263,0
2020-11-04,1224,1224,1224,1224,1224,0
2020-11-05,1194,1194,1194,1194,1194,0
2020-11-06,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-07,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-08,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-09,1207,1207,1207,1207,1207,0
2020-11-10,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,0"
dat <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume
2020-10-28,1384,1384,1384,1384,1384,0
2020-10-29,1297,1297,1297,1297,1297,0
2020-10-30,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-10-31,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-11-01,1283,1283,1283,1283,1283,0
2020-11-02,1284,1284,1284,1284,1284,0
2020-11-03,1263,1263,1263,1263,1263,0
2020-11-04,1224,1224,1224,1224,1224,0
2020-11-05,1194,1194,1194,1194,1194,0
2020-11-06,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-07,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-08,1196,1196,1196,1196,1196,0
2020-11-09,1207,1207,1207,1207,1207,0
2020-11-10,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,0"
target <- read.csv(text = Lines2, strip.white = TRUE)
```