# R Proper use for across() function with na.locf()

Tags: r, dplyr, across, coalescing

I am trying to replicate [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201654/combine-rows-by-group-with-differing-nas-in-each-row), but by using the updated syntax which uses the `across()` function and gets away from the deprecated `summarise_all()` and `funs()`.

### Starting Data

I have a database extract that one row per event type, like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df_start <- tibble(shipment = c(rep("A",4), rep("B",4)), 
             stop = rep(c(1,1,2,2), 2),
             arrive_pickup = as.POSIXct(c("2021-01-01 07:00:00 UTC",NA, NA, NA,"2021-06-05 12:10:00 UTC", NA, NA, NA)),
             depart_pickup = as.POSIXct(c(NA,"2021-01-01 08:40:00 UTC", NA, NA, NA, "2021-06-05 16:58:00 UTC", NA, NA)),
             arrive_delivery = as.POSIXct(c(NA, NA, "2021-01-05 10:00:00 UTC",NA, NA, NA,"2021-06-08 10:58:00 UTC", NA)),
             depart_delivery = as.POSIXct(c(NA, NA, NA, "2021-01-05 11:30:00 UTC",NA, NA, NA,"2021-06-08 13:50:00 UTC"))
)

> df_start
# A tibble: 8 x 6
  shipment  stop arrive_pickup       depart_pickup       arrive_delivery     depart_delivery    
  <chr>    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A            1 2021-01-01 07:00:00 NA                  NA                  NA                 
2 A            1 NA                  2021-01-01 08:40:00 NA                  NA                 
3 A            2 NA                  NA                  2021-01-05 10:00:00 NA                 
4 A            2 NA                  NA                  NA                  2021-01-05 11:30:00
5 B            1 2021-06-05 12:10:00 NA                  NA                  NA                 
6 B            1 NA                  2021-06-05 16:58:00 NA                  NA                 
7 B            2 NA                  NA                  2021-06-08 10:58:00 NA                 
8 B            2 NA                  NA                  NA                  2021-06-08 13:50:00
```

### Desired Outcome

... and I want to collapse the number of rows by grouping by either shipments and stops, or even just by shipments (I'm not sure if leaving `NA` present in the final dataframe will affect the answer, but I'm seeking to be able to solve it either way).

#### df_finish1  # One desired outcome

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  shipment  stop arrive_pickup       depart_pickup       arrive_delivery     depart_delivery    
  <chr>    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A            1 2021-01-01 07:00:00 2021-01-01 08:40:00 NA                  NA                 
2 A            2 NA                  NA                  2021-01-05 10:00:00 2021-01-05 11:30:00
3 B            1 2021-06-05 12:10:00 2021-06-05 16:58:00 NA                  NA                 
4 B            2 NA                  NA                  2021-06-08 10:58:00 2021-06-08 13:50:00
```

#### df_finish2 # Second/alternative desired outcome

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  shipment arrive_pickup       depart_pickup       arrive_delivery     depart_delivery    
  <chr>    <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A        2021-01-01 07:00:00 2021-01-01 08:40:00 2021-01-05 10:00:00 2021-01-05 11:30:00
2 B        2021-06-05 12:10:00 2021-06-05 16:58:00 2021-06-08 10:58:00 2021-06-08 13:50:00
```

### What I've researched and tried

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201654/combine-rows-by-group-with-differing-nas-in-each-row), which does work:

```
df_1 <- df_start %>% 
  group_by(shipment, stop) %>%   # Two groupings
  summarise_all(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE))) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==n())
  
> df_1
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   shipment, stop [4]
  shipment  stop arrive_pickup       depart_pickup       arrive_delivery     depart_delivery    
  <chr>    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A            1 2021-01-01 07:00:00 2021-01-01 08:40:00 NA                  NA                 
2 A            2 NA                  NA                  2021-01-05 10:00:00 2021-01-05 11:30:00
3 B            1 2021-06-05 12:10:00 2021-06-05 16:58:00 NA                  NA                 
4 B            2 NA                  NA                  2021-06-08 10:58:00 2021-06-08 13:50:00
```

```
df_2 <- df_start %>% 
  group_by(shipment) %>%   # Single grouping
  summarise_all(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE))) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==n())

> df_2
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   shipment [2]
  shipment  stop arrive_pickup       depart_pickup       arrive_delivery     depart_delivery    
  <chr>    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A            2 2021-01-01 07:00:00 2021-01-01 08:40:00 2021-01-05 10:00:00 2021-01-05 11:30:00
2 B            2 2021-06-05 12:10:00 2021-06-05 16:58:00 2021-06-08 10:58:00 2021-06-08 13:50:00
```

But what I see is that the `summarise_all()` function and the `funs()` function are deprecated and not to be used going forward, so I am trying to understand how to use the `across()` function properly, but without success:

```
df_3 <- df_start %>% 
  group_by(shipment) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything()), na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE))

> df_3 <- df_start %>% 
+   group_by(shipment) %>% 
+   summarise(across(everything()), na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE))
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..2`.
x Input `..2` must be size 4 or 1, not 8.
i An earlier column had size 4.
i Input `..2` is `na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: shipment = "A".
```

I've read through the `vignette("colwise")` which describe the differences and suggests I would just replace the syntax as shown above, but clearly I'm not getting it right.  Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have couple of syntax issues in the code.

1 - The arguments `.cols` and `.fns` are inside `across`, in your code `across` function gets closed after `everything()` (`across(everything())`).

2. When you are using `.` in `across` you need to prefix it with `~` to specify that you are using lambda expression for the function passed. (See `.fns` argument in `?across`).

Incorporating this changes you can use -

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df_start %>% 
  group_by(shipment) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE)))
```

However, `across` has `everything()` as default `.cols` argument and you can also apply the function without the need of `~`, so another way to write this would be -

```
df_start %>% 
  group_by(shipment) %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = na.locf, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I spent 90 minutes trying everything EXCEPT catching my misplaced parentheses.  Getting it to work is helpful for me and seeing the alternative ways of applying is great.  Much appreciated for the help.

Answer (score 1):

here is one option where after grouping by 'shipment', 'stop', order the columns basedon the NA values and then `filter` away rows having all NAs

```
library(dplyr)
df_start %>%
     group_by(shipment, stop) %>% 
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ .[order(is.na(.))])) %>% 
     filter(!if_all(everything(), is.na)) %>% 
     ungroup
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  shipment  stop arrive_pickup       depart_pickup       arrive_delivery     depart_delivery    
  <chr>    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A            1 2021-01-01 07:00:00 2021-01-01 08:40:00 NA                  NA                 
2 A            2 NA                  NA                  2021-01-05 10:00:00 2021-01-05 11:30:00
3 B            1 2021-06-05 12:10:00 2021-06-05 16:58:00 NA                  NA                 
4 B            2 NA                  NA                  2021-06-08 10:58:00 2021-06-08 13:50:00
```

---

For the second case, use `across`

```
df_start %>% 
   group_by(shipment) %>% 
   dplyr::summarise(across(contains("_"), ~ na.omit(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  shipment arrive_pickup       depart_pickup       arrive_delivery     depart_delivery    
  <chr>    <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A        2021-01-01 07:00:00 2021-01-01 08:40:00 2021-01-05 10:00:00 2021-01-05 11:30:00
2 B        2021-06-05 12:10:00 2021-06-05 16:58:00 2021-06-08 10:58:00 2021-06-08 13:50:00
```

---

In the OP's, it was using `na.locf` instead of `na.omit` and also there is a typo i.e. `across` was closed without any arguments i.e. if we check the code on this post, the syntax used is

```
...across(everything(), ~ .. # correct
...across(everything()) ... # incorrect
```

Thus, we need to just change the `)` to the end along with `~` which specifies for lambda function (or otherwise `function(.) .`

```
df_start %>% 
  group_by(shipment) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE)))
```